# Reg Expression to replace sub-string with special character in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

Can any one help me to build a reg expression to replace a sub-string(with special character) with in a parent string. Here is my sample string

```
var sample = "Logic @@Current Month (MM) -- @@Current Month (MM)";
var replace =  "@@MM";
```

In this case i want to replace all the occurrence of  '@@Current Month (MM)' with '@@MM'.

I wrote something similar to this

```
var reg = new RegExp("@@Current Month (MM)", "g");
sample = sample.replace(reg, "@@MM");
```

It fails because replace content include '(' and ')'. Can any one help me to rewrite this..?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.replace(/@@Current Month \(([^)]*?)\)/g, '@@$1')`

Comment: Thanks Tushar. Its a good option.

Comment: Is this correct answer? You want the replacement string dynamic(one in the brackets) or it is `MM` always?

Comment: Yes its always 'MM' for '@@Current Month (MM)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape parenthesis since it has special meaning([Capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)) in regex.

```
var reg = new RegExp("@@Current Month \\(MM\\)", "g");
sample = sample.replace(reg, "@@MM");

// or

sample = sample.replace(/@@Current Month \(MM\)/g, "@@MM");
```

```js
var sample = "Logic @@Current Month (MM) -- @@Current Month (MM)";

var reg = new RegExp("@@Current Month \\(MM\\)", "g");
console.log(sample.replace(reg, "@@MM"));

console.log(sample.replace(/@@Current Month \(MM\)/g, "@@MM"));
```